# Is __init__ a must to be able to set object instance values?

Tags: python, constructor, initialization

I look at [this](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html#doctype) and they create a `Post` object that does not have an `__init__` function with:  `first = Post(title='My First Blog Post, yay!', published=True)`. So I wonder - can any Python 3.5+ object be created without an `__init__` function setting members like this:

```
class Apple:
    id = 66
    w = 99

an_apple = Apple(id=44, w=55)
```

Comment: It inherits `__init__` from `DocType` class: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/b71cb29a5b72c653761464b23c81fcab89b588da/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py#L104

Comment: Did you *try* it? What happened? And what does that result tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would run the code you wrote here you would see that the answer was **no** because you would get this error `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`. Read what @AshwiniChaudhary very carefully, the function you read about **does have `__init__`**, it just inherits it from somewhere else.

See this part in the code? `class Post(DocType):`

It means `Post` is a class that inherits everything from another class named `DocType`. The rest of the code for that class just adds more attributes.